# Drag and drop between linear layouts exchange views in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout

I have image views in two linear layouts. I want to drag image from first linear layout to second one in such a manner, when I drop the image to second linear layout, its image should come in first linear layout. I have done the research where I found to drag and drop image from first to second. But the image of second is not coming in first. 
Following is the link which I am referring for drag and drop http://javapapers.com/android/android-drag-and-drop/

The problem is the images are not getting exchange. I am able to drag and drop from first to second.

Kindly advice the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this?

Comment: @Sanchit Paurush Did you get any solution ? I have the same query

Answer (score 0):

You can see the example provided by google on their developer page - [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: This code is of drag and drop. I mentioned in my question that I need to exchange the content of linear layout after successful drag and drop